# How to avoid slice reference to the same memory block

Tags: sql, go

I met a problem when query from Database and tried to insert into a slice(contains some map[string]interface{})
Even I already used make to create a new memory block, the slice seems always mapping to a same memory block.

```
type DBResult []map[string]interface{}

func ResultRows(rows *sql.Rows, limit int) (DBResult, error) {
    cols, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    vals := make([]sql.RawBytes, len(cols))
    scanArgs := make([]interface{}, len(vals))
    for i := range vals {
        scanArgs[i] = &vals[i]
    }

    if limit > QUERY_HARD_LIMIT {
        limit = QUERY_HARD_LIMIT
    }

    res := make(DBResult, 0, limit)
    for rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(scanArgs...)
        m := make(map[string]interface{})

        for i := range vals {
            m[cols[i]] = vals[i]
        }
        /* Append m to res */
        res = append(res, m)
        /* The value of m has been changed */
        fmt.Printf("lib: m:\n\n%s\n\n", m)
        /* When printing res, always mapping to the same memory block */
        fmt.Printf("lib: res:\n\n%s\n\n", res)
    }

    return res, err
}
```

The following is the result, you can find the contents of res are the same

> m = map[comment:first_comment id:0]
>
> res = [map[id:0 comment:first_comment]]
>
> m = map[id:1 comment:first_comment]
>
> res = [map[id:1 comment:first_comment] map[id:1 comment:first_comment]]
>
> m = map[id:2 comment:first_comment]
>
> res = [map[id:2 comment:first_comment] map[id:2 comment:first_comment] map[id:2 comment:first_comment]]

My expect of res = [map[id:0 comment:first_comment] map[id:1 comment:first_comment] map[id:2 comment:first_comment]]

Thanks for watching

Comment: Tag dbms used, to get better assistance  - faster.

Comment: That's how slices work. Maybe you could show a shorter and standalone program? In any case: You'll have to rework your solution.

Comment: In a shorter program without sql, that is ok to append the slices.

Comment: First check for the error of Scan.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

according to the document of Rows (https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Scan):

---

Scan copies the columns in the current row into the values pointed at by dest.

If an argument has type *[]byte, Scan saves in that argument a copy of the corresponding data. The copy is owned by the caller and can be modified and held indefinitely. The copy can be avoided by using an argument of type *RawBytes instead; see the documentation for RawBytes for restrictions on its use.

If an argument has type *interface{}, Scan copies the value provided by the underlying driver without conversion. If the value is of type []byte, a copy is made and the caller owns the result.

---

in your case, you use RawBytes as argument of Scan. That might be the problem you got. Try other type as argument of Scan function.

Comment: RawBytes is a byte slice that holds a reference to memory owned by the database itself. After a Scan into a RawBytes, the slice is only valid until the next call to Next, Scan, or Close.

Comment: Thanks, when I used []byte instead of Rawbytes, it is been OK.